# Set sprite to default color

Tags: ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I have a sprite and I set its color and then I want to set it back to the old color(Default color) how can I do it

here a simple code

```
 sprite = [[CCSprite alloc] initWithFile:@"zero.png"];
 sprite.color = ccc3(255, 223, 0);
```

....

How to set it back to the default color

sprite.color = ???????

or I have to find out the default color by find that old color RGB code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sprite.color = ccWHITE;
```

And I have to add some text here so SO will accept the answer. :)

ccWHITE is the same as ccc3(255, 255, 255)

Comment: Oh yes it so easy... = ="

Thx u very much